# Скрыть/Показать элемент jQuery

Tags: jquery

Приветствую, ответы которые я посмотрел тут и во поисковых системах мне не помогли.

Есть у меня форма

```
<form class="form-inline" id="editName">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="first" placeholder="Имя">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="first" placeholder="Фамилия">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Сохранить</button>
</form>
```

Мне нужно показать её или скрыть по нажатию на ссылку.
По умолчанию она должна быть, варианты из первых трех страниц Google я перепробовал.

Не работает

```
$("#editorName").click(function() {
    $(this).find("form#editName").toggle();
});
```

Comment: а чем toggle( ) не устраивает?

Comment: @Konst я же говорю не работает.

Comment: работает http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/ch4LokLt/

Comment: $("#editorName").click(function() {
    $("#editName").toggle();
});

Answer (score 2):

Вот тебе решение, думаю че куда разберешься.

```
            $( "#button-slide-l" ).click(function() {

                if ( $("div.content").hasClass("close") == true ) {
                    $('div.content').removeClass('close');
                }
                else {
                    $('div.content').addClass('close');
                }


            });
```